# var someSome = (function () { ... } ()); a weird javascript asking?

Tags: javascript

I cannot think of the term that JavaScript developers use for this kind of practice.

```
 var someSome = (function () { ... } ());
```

-- Wrapping function within brackets. I vaguely remember someone was calling this fiif? fiff?

And there were many advantages and it was recommended java scripting practice.

Anyone got clue what I am talking about and why is it a good practice?

it might have been even without assignment like below

```
(function () { ... } ());
```

Comment: IIFE. Mostly used for just-in-time-style variable declarations (as seen here) and avoiding scope pollution.

Comment: Thank you Niet!!! Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)

Answer (score 0):

Self executing function. Often used as a wrapper around a function block to immediately invoke it, as well as give it closure.